# Objective-c updateSearchResultsForSearchController not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to apply a search feature to my UITableView. I added a search bar to the storeyboard scene like so:

[image]

then in my header file, I added the UISearchControllerDelegate and UISearchController like so:

```
@interface LHFileBrowser : UITableViewController UISearchControllerDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray * tableData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *NavBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *results;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *controller;

@end
```

and I added my updateSearchResultsForSearchController method to .m file

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {


    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains [c] %@", self.controller.searchBar.text];

    self.results = [self.tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

}
```

and I put a break point at NSPredicate and when I try to use my search bar, I get nothing, it does not hit my break point so updateSearchResultsForSearchController is not being called. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your TableViewController as the delegate for a number of things, so in `viewDidLoad` add:

```
self.controller.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.controller.delegate = self;
self.controller.searchBar.delegate = self;
```

Also there's a typo in your interface, there should be a `<` before `UISearchControllerDelegate`.

(As an aside, I'd recommend changing `controller` -> `searchController` to make your code less confusing.)

Comment: I added your 3 lines of code to viewDidLoad and same thing, the updateSearchResultsForSearchController method is not being called

Comment: You need to have `UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating` in your interface

Comment: Your code posted only shows `UISearchControllerDelegate`